# find_last_of for double quote at end of string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to see if the end of the string being read is a `"`. If it isn't, I want it to print out something.

```
if(!line.find_last_of("\"")) {
    cout << "Extra parameter is typed."; 
    continue;
```

I was trying to use `find_last_of` but when I run it extra parameter is printed no matter if it the command has extra parameters. Example:

```
lc "file.txt"   -suppose to true so it's suppose to continue program but returns false
lc "file.txt" lk  - suppose to return false and it does but should only return false for this type of case.
```

Comment: **Return value:**
*position of the found character or npos if no such character is found.* You should be checking it against `!= std::string::npos`, which I believe is -1, which doesn't suit your condition.

Comment: @chris This is true although not sufficient, since he needs to check that it is at the *end* of his string, not just somewhere in his string.

Comment: @Ivan, Yes, I was merely commenting. I guess I should have made it clear that checking against `npos` is the way to go for just finding a string, but here, other return values are of use as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I think @Jonathon Seng's answer is good (and have up-voted it), I think there's another possibility that might be worth mentioning. Instead of `mystring.at(mystring.length()-1)`, you could use `*mystring.rbegin()`:

```
if (*line.rbegin() == '"') ...
```

Of course, you still have to check that the string isn't empty as well. For this, I'd normally prefer `!line.empty()` over `line.length() > 0`, so the final version becomes:

```
if (!line.empty() && *line.rbegin() == '"') {
    // whatever
}
```

Edit: note that the test for `!line.empty()` must be first. `&&` evaluates its left operand, and then if (and only if) that evaluates to `true`, evaluates its right operand. We need to verify that the line isn't empty *first*, then check the character only if the string isn't non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

You could compare `line.at(line.length() - 1)` to `'"'` (after establishing `line.length() > 0`).

Comment: line.length() could be also equal to 1

Comment: Then it would test position 0, which is the last position.  That wasn't mentioned as invalid, so I didn't assume it.

Comment: You dont understand. You have a mistake in code. line.length() should be >= not just > than 1

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be

```
if( (!(line.find_last_of("\"") == line.length() - 1)) && (line.length() > 0) ) {
   <do your stuff>;
}
```

Since string::find_last_of() returns the last position of the given character if it is found (at least once) anywhere in the line. So if it is the second-to-last character, it will return line.length()-2 which will cause your boolean expression (the if condition) to behave the same way as it if was the last character.

Checking that `line.length()` is greater than zero is essential as if `line.length() == 0`, this may return true since `string::find_last_of()` returns `string::npos` (which typically equals -1) if it cannot find the matching pattern.

Also don't forget to null-check `line` but that's a given if you like programming defensively.

Comment: Wouldnt be easier just check last character equality to `"` ?

Comment: Probably faster (performance-wise) although I would argue that unless this is in the inner loop of some very fast piece of code that's probably premature optimization. I personally prefer to avoid directly accessing string types as character arrays (using string::at() etc.) where possible. There's nothing *inherently* wrong with it but I've shot myself in the foot doing character fetching from a specified index too often. It's easy to mess up your math and walk off the end of the string (throws an exception). I'd prefer to use an approach that requires less math :)